# Battery management tool in Linux

Tags: linux, fedora

I want to stop battery recharging once it has reached a specific level, like 80%. I have Lenovo Z560 laptop with windows 7 and it came with a software to manage battery charging.

But now I have changed my OS to Fedora 17 and the software is not available for linux.

Is it possible to manage battery charging level in linux?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Google is your best friend

Comment: @mgorven To extend battery lifespan. According to lenovo energy management it prevents overcharging and increases battery life

Comment: Some laptops (e.g. Samsung 300E4Z) have a BIOS option doing just that. Check your BIOS setup utility.